# How to avoid clear text password in JDBC data source in Tomcat 10

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, datasource, password-encryption, tomcat10

I am using Tomcat 10 and added a JDBC data source in server.xml with clear text password. I want to use an encrypted database password for security purposes.

How can I add a custom data source factory in server.xml file of Tomcat 10 to achieve data source password encryption/decryption?

Comment: Just as a side note, the encryption can happen within your Java code, at the application layer.  You don't necessarily have to rely on the database for encrypting/hashing passwords.

Comment: Related: [tomcat server.xml encrypted password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607316/tomcat-server-xml-encrypted-password)